# How to Convert SQL query with Where condition and case to MDX

Tags: mysql, mdx

Im new to MDX and I also reviewed the SQL to MDX Query comparison. But still Im not able to get the hang of MDX.

I'm trying to convert the below SQL to MDX.

```
SELECT CAST(A.Num AS FLOAT)/A.Denom AS "Denial Rate"
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN LargestAdjustmentType = 'Denial' THEN LargestAdjustmentType end) AS Num, COUNT(*) AS Denom FROM vwremits) a
```

Ive writtrying to write as MDX

```
Select [Measures].[Denial Rate]
 AS [Measures].[Count] AS [AdjustmentType].["Denial"]
```

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what measures & hierarchies exist in your cube structure this question is impossible to answer - so here is a stab in the dark:

```
WITH [Measures].[Denial Rate] AS
     [Measures].[Count]
SELECT
 {} ON 0,
 [Measures].[Denial Rate] ON 1
FROM [CubeName]
WHERE [AdjustmentType].[AdjustmentType].[Denial];
```

Or just:

```
SELECT
 [AdjustmentType].[AdjustmentType].[Denial] ON 0,
 [Measures].[Count] ON 1
FROM [CubeName];
```